# how to insert postgresql table using C# dataTable & postgresql COPY, without EF core

Tags: c#, postgresql, winforms, datatable, postgresql-copy

I want to insert into postgresql(12.9) table using C# datatable object in winform.

> [image]  ◀ DataTable object

I want to use a function like [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html).
Is there a way to resolve a C# DataTable object to STDIN ?

The reason I don't want to do EF core is because it's difficult to find EF core tutorials for postgresql, so I don't want to try it.

There is a condition for doing this.

1. DataTable data built in C# cannot be converted to csv. (by the way, Is there a way to include csv in c# winform exe? Then I can use the csv method)

Comment: The whole idea behind EF Core is that it's an abstraction away from your database; you don't folllow "an EFCore tutorial for pg" you just follow an "EF core tutorial". I can write you one in a single SO answer that will get you going.. don't shy away from trying; it makes life very easy!

Comment: Of course DataTables can be converted to CSV - you seem to set a lot of barriers for yourself in your programming life. There is a way to do nearly anything(but not always economically viable perhaps), and with something like CsvHelper it's like, two lines of code or something